# How to set icon in CustomRadioButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I want to set the icons / images as per both gender. Can anybody please provide me help!.
I have used the package `custom_radio_grouped_button:`

```
Container(
                      child: CustomRadioButton(
                        elevation: 0,
                        absoluteZeroSpacing: false,
                        unSelectedColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                        buttonLables: [
                          'Male',
                          'Female',
                        ],
                        buttonValues: [
                          "MALE",
                          "FEMALE",
                        ],
                        buttonTextStyle: ButtonTextStyle(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                        radioButtonValue: (value) {
                          print(value);
                        },
                        selectedColor: Colors.green,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

As Theophile said, **custom_radio_grouped_button** package doesn’t allow to add icons or images so far.

However, if you want to take advantage of the rest of features this package offers but you don’t want to reinvent the wheel, you can then copy the code of the package to a new file on your project, and make the edits that you need to make it work as you expect.

**Even though I don't recommend doing this as general practice**, given that I couldn't easily find another widget to solve this, and that custom_radio_grouped_button has a relatively small implementation, you can take this approach in this case.

As an example, I’ve done so and here is the code with the modifications. You can copy/paste this code on a local file on your project (maybe named as **custom_radio_button_shape.dart**):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class CustomRadioButtonShape<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomRadioButtonShape({
    this.buttonWidgets,
    this.buttonValues,
    this.buttonTextStyle = const ButtonTextStyleShape(),
    this.autoWidth = false,
    this.radioButtonValue,
    this.unSelectedColor,
    this.unSelectedBorderColor,
    this.padding = 3,
    this.spacing = 0.0,
    this.selectedColor,
    this.selectedBorderColor,
    this.height = 35,
    this.width = 100,
    this.enableButtonWrap = false,
    this.horizontal = false,
    this.enableShape = false,
    this.elevation = 10,
    this.defaultSelected,
    this.customShape,
    this.absoluteZeroSpacing = false,
    this.wrapAlignment = WrapAlignment.start,
  })  : assert(buttonWidgets.length == buttonValues.length,
  "Button values list and button lables list should have same number of eliments "),
        assert(unSelectedColor != null, "Unselected color cannot be null"),
        assert(buttonValues.toSet().length == buttonValues.length,
        "Multiple buttons with same value cannot exist"),
  // assert(buttonLables.toSet().length == buttonLables.length,
  //     "Multiple buttons label wth same value cannot exist"),
        assert(selectedColor != null, "Selected color cannot be null");

  ///Orientation of the Button Group
  final bool horizontal;

  ///Values of button
  final List<T> buttonValues;

  ///This option will make sure that there is no spacing in between buttons
  final bool absoluteZeroSpacing;

  ///Default value is 35
  final double height;
  double padding;

  ///Spacing between buttons
  double spacing;

  ///Default selected value
  final T defaultSelected;

  ///Only applied when in vertical mode
  ///This will use minimum space required
  ///If enables it will ignore [width] field
  final bool autoWidth;

  ///Use this if you want to keep width of all the buttons same
  final double width;

  final List<Widget> buttonWidgets;

  ///Styling class for label
  final ButtonTextStyleShape buttonTextStyle;

  final void Function(T) radioButtonValue;

  ///Unselected Color of the button
  final Color unSelectedColor;

  ///Selected Color of button
  final Color selectedColor;

  ///Unselected Color of the button border
  final Color unSelectedBorderColor;

  ///Selected Color of button border
  final Color selectedBorderColor;

  /// A custom Shape can be applied (will work only if [enableShape] is true)
  final ShapeBorder customShape;

  ///alignment for button when [enableButtonWrap] is true
  final WrapAlignment wrapAlignment;

  /// This will enable button wrap (will work only if orientation is vertical)
  final bool enableButtonWrap;

  ///if true button will have rounded corners
  ///If you want custom shape you can use [customShape] property
  final bool enableShape;
  final double elevation;

  _CustomRadioButtonShapeState createState() => _CustomRadioButtonShapeState();
}

class _CustomRadioButtonShapeState extends State<CustomRadioButtonShape> {
  Widget _currentSelectedWidget;

  Color borderColor(index) => (_currentSelectedWidget == widget.buttonWidgets[index] ? widget.selectedBorderColor : widget.unSelectedBorderColor) ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.defaultSelected != null) {
      if (widget.buttonValues.contains(widget.defaultSelected)) {
        int index = widget.buttonValues.indexOf(widget.defaultSelected);
        _currentSelectedWidget = widget.buttonWidgets[index];
      } else
        throw Exception("Default Value not found in button value list");
    }
  }

  List<Widget> _buildButtonsColumn() {
    return widget.buttonValues.map((e) {
      int index = widget.buttonValues.indexOf(e);
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(widget.padding),
        child: Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(widget.absoluteZeroSpacing ? 0 : 4),
          color: _currentSelectedWidget == widget.buttonWidgets[index]
              ? widget.selectedColor
              : widget.unSelectedColor,
          elevation: widget.elevation,
          shape: widget.enableShape
              ? widget.customShape == null
              ? RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
          )
              : widget.customShape
              : null,
          child: Container(
            height: widget.height,
            child: MaterialButton(
              shape: widget.enableShape
                  ? widget.customShape == null
                  ? OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: borderColor(index), width: 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
              )
                  : widget.customShape
                  : OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: borderColor(index), width: 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                widget.radioButtonValue(e);
                setState(() {
                  _currentSelectedWidget = widget.buttonWidgets[index];
                });
              },
              child: Center(
                child: widget.buttonWidgets[index],/*Text(
                  widget.buttonLables[index],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: widget.buttonTextStyle.textStyle.copyWith(
                    color: _currentSelectedLabel == widget.buttonLables[index]
                        ? widget.buttonTextStyle.selectedColor
                        : widget.buttonTextStyle.unSelectedColor,
                  ),
                ),*/
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  List<Widget> _buildButtonsRow() {
    return widget.buttonValues.map((e) {
      int index = widget.buttonValues.indexOf(e);
      return Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(widget.absoluteZeroSpacing ? 0 : 4),
        color: _currentSelectedWidget == widget.buttonWidgets[index]
            ? widget.selectedColor
            : widget.unSelectedColor,
        elevation: widget.elevation,
        shape: widget.enableShape
            ? widget.customShape == null
            ? RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
        )
            : widget.customShape
            : null,
        child: Container(
          height: widget.height,
          width: widget.autoWidth ? null : widget.width,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250),
          child: MaterialButton(
            shape: widget.enableShape
                ? widget.customShape == null
                ? OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: borderColor(index), width: 1),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            )
                : widget.customShape
                : OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: borderColor(index), width: 1),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.radioButtonValue(e);
              setState(() {
                _currentSelectedWidget = widget.buttonWidgets[index];
              });
            },
            child: Center(
              child: widget.buttonWidgets[index],/*Text(
                widget.buttonLables[index],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 1,
                style: widget.buttonTextStyle.textStyle.copyWith(
                  color: _currentSelectedLabel == widget.buttonLables[index]
                      ? widget.buttonTextStyle.selectedColor
                      : widget.buttonTextStyle.unSelectedColor,
                ),
              ),*/
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.absoluteZeroSpacing) {
      widget.spacing = 0;
      widget.padding = 0;
    }
    return _buildRadioButtons();
  }

  _buildRadioButtons() {
    if (widget.horizontal)
      return Container(
        height: widget.height * (widget.buttonWidgets.length * 1.5) +
            widget.padding * 2 * widget.buttonWidgets.length,
        child: Center(
          child: CustomListViewSpacingShape(
            spacing: widget.spacing,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: _buildButtonsColumn(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    if (!widget.horizontal && widget.enableButtonWrap)
      return Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Wrap(
            spacing: widget.spacing,
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            alignment: widget.wrapAlignment,
            children: _buildButtonsRow(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    if (!widget.horizontal && !widget.enableButtonWrap)
      return Container(
        height: widget.height + widget.padding * 2,
        child: Center(
          child: CustomListViewSpacingShape(
            spacing: widget.spacing,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: _buildButtonsRow(),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}

class ButtonTextStyleShape {
  ///Selected color of Text
  final Color selectedColor;

  ///Unselected color of Text
  final Color unSelectedColor;
  final TextStyle textStyle;

  const ButtonTextStyleShape({
    this.selectedColor = Colors.white,
    this.unSelectedColor = Colors.black,
    this.textStyle = const TextStyle(),
  });
}

class CustomListViewSpacingShape extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;
  final double spacing;
  final Axis scrollDirection;
  CustomListViewSpacingShape(
      {@required this.children,
        this.spacing = 0.0,
        this.scrollDirection = Axis.vertical});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
      children: children
          .map((c) => Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(spacing),
        child: c,
      ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Then you could use it as follows (for this example I'm also using the package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_icons which includes tons of great icons, but you can use your own custom images if you need), and [this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU2mJ.jpg)

```
CustomRadioButtonShape(
  elevation: 0,
  absoluteZeroSpacing: true,
  unSelectedColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
  buttonWidgets: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          FontAwesome.male,
          size: 15,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
          child: Text('Male'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          FontAwesome.female,
          size: 15,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
          child: Text('Female'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
  buttonValues: [
    "MALE",
    "FEMALE",
  ],
  buttonTextStyle: ButtonTextStyleShape(
    selectedColor: Colors.white,
    unSelectedColor: Colors.black,
    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)
  ),
  radioButtonValue: (value) {
    print(value);
  },
  selectedColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
),
```

Hope this helps.